# do not want to load the CSS class

Tags: html, css

i've added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../www.assistans.tv/css/menu.css" type="text/css">


<div class="assloggo"></div>
```

but it dont load the css class i have added to "assloggo"

```
.assloggo {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        float:right;
    }
```

whats wrong? the url is: http://109.74.0.128/~app/assistanstv/assistanstv/www.assistans.tv/tv.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide enough information *in the question* so we are able to help you.

Comment: But, just to give you a hand... your CSS is loading, but the class is inside a media query: `@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {`

Comment: @PraveenPoonia: And what debugging have you done to confirm that assumption?  The URL seems to work fine.

Comment: I don't see `<div class="assloggo"></div>` on the linked page

Answer (score 0):

I think you have put that CSS class inside media query @media screen and (max-width: 860px) { }. And you are looking in a big width screen. Please reszie your screen and check. It will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#react-main-mount > .assloggo {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

and pull-out this css from media css

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 860px) {
    .menu {
        width:100%;
        padding:10px 18px;
        box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        border-radius:3px;
        background:#303030;
  #react-main-mount > .assloggo {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  }

Comment: Make sure opening and closing brackets should be correct
@media screen and (min-width: 860px) { 
        .menu { 
        width:100%;
        padding:10px 18px;
        box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        border-radius:3px;
        background:#303030;
        }
        
        #react-main-mount > .assloggo { 
        position:relative; display:inline-block; float:right;
         }
        }

Comment: try this  outside media css
#react-main-mount > .assloggo {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}

Comment: I just did, without any result

Comment: Please create a fiddle link for this issue

Answer (score -1):

Well it is because you are have multiple closing `}` on the same line which causing your problem/error.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 860px) { 
.menu { 
width:100%; 
padding:10px 18px; 
box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); 
border-radius:3px; 
background:#303030; 
} 
.assloggo { 
position:relative; 
display:inline-block; 
float:right; 
} 
}
```

Why should you use `>`> try do .assloggo without any other class usage before, if this class is the only one in your webpage.

Regards Martijn